# How to set valid certification path when connecting to redis using SSL in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, ssl, redis

I want to connect to redis by using SSL. I set up host, port etc. but when i'm setting...

```
spring.redis.ssl=true
```

and when i run the application i got following error:

> org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException:
> **Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to
>
> XXX:XXX**     at
> org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.translateException(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1689)
> ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
>
> **Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
> unable to find valid certification path to requested target**     at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:349)
> ~[na:na]

Actually my certificate (test.pem) is in resources folder in spring boot apllication project.
Where should i put the certificate file or how to set the path to this file?
I want to set it by application.yml or by java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This configuration works in my case:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RedisSSLConfiguration {

  @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
  private String host;

  @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
  private int port;

  @Value("${spring.redis.password}")
  private String password;

  @Value("${spring.redis.ssl:false}")
  private boolean sslEnabled;

  private final ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

  @Bean
  RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() throws IOException {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(host);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(port);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(password);

    LettuceClientConfiguration.LettuceClientConfigurationBuilder lettuceClientConfigurationBuilder =
        LettuceClientConfiguration.builder();

    if (sslEnabled){
      SslOptions sslOptions = SslOptions.builder()
          .trustManager(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:redis.pem").getFile())
          .build();

      ClientOptions clientOptions = ClientOptions
          .builder()
          .sslOptions(sslOptions)
          .protocolVersion(ProtocolVersion.RESP3)
          .build();

      lettuceClientConfigurationBuilder
          .clientOptions(clientOptions)
          .useSsl();
    }

    LettuceClientConfiguration lettuceClientConfiguration = lettuceClientConfigurationBuilder.build();

    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, lettuceClientConfiguration);
  }

}
```

Comment: we're having same code.. but are having the .pem file in a folder. it seems to be not working with relative path or abs path

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant since you are using a cert file, but we had some issues with redis after turning on ssl and we solved them by changing from lettuce to jedis, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77458590/924036.